# SQL speed and optimization for nested query

Tags: mysql, algorithm, sorting

**Consider a table schema to store color and hexcodes**

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_master_colors` (
  `color_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `color_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `color_hex` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `color_hex_hashed` varchar(7) NOT NULL,
  `color_r` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `color_g` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `color_b` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('1','2','3') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `inserted_ts` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_ts` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_ts` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

*Now I have to query to extract all **red colors***

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_master_colors 
WHERE color_name LIKE "red%"
ORDER BY color_g DESC, color_b ASC, color_r DESC
```

*Now I have **2 more variants** of this query*

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * FROM tbl_master_colors 
WHERE color_name LIKE "red%") s
ORDER BY color_g DESC, color_b ASC, color_r DESC;

SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * FROM tbl_master_colors 
ORDER BY color_g DESC, color_b ASC, color_r DESC) s
WHERE color_name LIKE "red%"
```

> **Question:** Which of the above 2 select query variants is the fastest and why?
> If possible please arrange all three of them in order with reason.
>
> **Consider:** The dataset to have *9 x 10^6* data entries, and output in the range of *10^4*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since MySQL 5.7, all these three statements have the same performance.  The derived table (subquery in FROM clause) will be merged into outer query. (See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/derived-table-optimization.html).

I do not think the SQL standard guarantees the same ordering for the last query as for the other two, but MySQL will also merge the ORDER clause into the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is the best.
If you can't modify your table with an index on color_name i suggest make a field with the principal color in int.

Comment: Please consider it to be a sample example of a big problem. and the question was "Which of the above 2 select query variants is the fastest and why?"